# How do I display Select rows from a table in C#

Tags: c#, database

C# Visual Studio 2012 asp.net

Let's say I have a table with three rows:
1. Justin
2. Dave
3. Justin

I want to display only the rows with Justin.

How do I do that?

What I've done so far is created a grid view of the table but that displays the entire table. I see that in the grid view there is an option to configure that data source and add query...

I need to write something like select * from names where FName = "Justin" - where do i write that code???

but i don't really know how to use it. It's a bit confusing.

help??

Comment: why you are not putting condition in datatable itself?

Comment: It sounds like you need to read a good overview of how DataAccess in C# works. Once you have an idea of all of that, you can then decide how you want to interact with the database. There's a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761933/introduction-to-database-interaction-with-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

while binding data to gridview you bind data-table, to that table you can do select option,

with select option you can do query on datatable and select desired data.

[Check this .select()](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable-select)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use RowFilter on DataView