# How to update SQL Server database remotely using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, remote-access

I'm a beginner to Programming. But I'm working on a C# project and what i need to do is update my SQL Server database remotely. I mean when a one client update the database send that updated data to other clients. I'm using a SQL Server 2008. I don't have a any idea to do this task.

Thanks for your kind reply's.

Comment: [How to enable remote connections to SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx)

Comment: Although it's considered insecure and bad programming to allow Internet access to an SQL server directly.  If you want a centralized database you probably want a Web Service (for example ASP.NET Web Api) which marshals access to the database for you.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Thank you very much for your tip! Can i use windows form instead of using ASP.NET . I mean if their was a any method to share my centralized database other clients.

Comment: It's not a small topic but a web service can be accessed from anything which can make HTTP requests.  Which is pretty much everything (windows, mac, linux, mobile phones).

Comment: @PasinduM - If you don't want to use `ASP.NET`, I would instead opt for using [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) over `WinForms`.  It is much more flexible and powerful.

Comment: @PasinduM Windows Forms is a type of client... it would not host the service.  It theoretically could but you wouldn't want to.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Thanks for kind reply's What i need to do is retrieve the data remotely to my windows form.please tell me what should be the best option?

Comment: @Brian Thanks for kind reply What i need to do is retrieve the data remotely to my windows form.please tell me what should be the best option?

Comment: @PasinduM - As Trevor Elliot already suggested, use [Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228289(v=vs.90).aspx).

Comment: If you are using frequent updates for backup purpose then I would suggest as others suggested above to use a centralized database with Services,i.e. WCF Rest (as you can use it on almost all platforms) with WPF app as client. Yeah! It seems too broad  for a beginner but its a good start. Or You can go for ASP.Net as well. To get data on your second server you have do a little reasearch on Sql jobs for scheduling the syncing of data between two remote databases

Answer (score 0):

The question is too broad.  You're asking for a general programming and database connectivity tutorial.  I recommend you start with a guide, online tutorial, or book and return to StackOverflow with specific code-based questions when a particular step along that process does not behave the way you expected it to (starting with a search of course to avoid duplicate questions).

Here's an existing StackOverflow question with many links to further reading: [Introduction to database interaction with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761933/introduction-to-database-interaction-with-c-sharp)